# Remove an array depending its values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [complet_title] => test1
        [have_background] => 0
        [condition_type] => 1
        [state] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [complet_title] => test2
        [have_background] => 1
        [condition_type] => 1
        [state] => 0
    )
)
```

My php code :

```
foreach($a_sliders as $k => $slider){
        switch($slider['condition_type']){
            case 1:
                if($slider['state'] == 1){
                    if(Test::check($id, $server)){
                        unset($a_sliders[$k]);
                    }else{

                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

In the `else` I want to delete the sub-array with the `condition_type = 1` and `state = 0`. It's possible to do that whitout a suplimentaire foreach ? Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Something like `if ($slider['state'] == 0 && $slider['condition_type'] == 1) unset($k);` if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_filter($array, function($v){return  ($v['condition_type'] != 1) || ($v['state'] != 0);})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove($arr, $key1, $val1, $key2, $val2){
        $foundKey = '';
        foreach($arr as $k=>$a){
            if($a[$key1] == $val1 && $a[$key2] == $val2){
                $foundKey = $k;
            }
        }
        if(isset($arr[$foundkey])){
        unset($arr[$foundkey]);
    }

return $arr;
}
```

Now call remove function:

```
remove($arr, 'state', '0', 'condition_type', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this,

```
foreach($a_sliders as $k => $slider){
        switch($slider['condition_type']){
            case 1:
                if($slider['state'] == 1){
                    if(Test::check($id, $server)){
                        unset($a_sliders[$k]);
                    }
                }
           // your conditions are likely to be met here
                else if ($slider['state'] == 0 && $slider['condition_type'] == 1){                                
                        unset($a_sliders[$k]);
            }
        }
    }
```